# How to fix OCI runtime exec failed "exec format error" in Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I'm setting up ArchiveBox using the Docker image and instructions found [here](https://github.com/pirate/ArchiveBox/wiki/Docker#docker-compose). Though it appears to have been successfully setup on my computer, I cannot use the main command to add an individual link.

The Setup section instructs you to

- `clone` a github project,
- `cd` into that folder, `mkdir` data,
- `chmod 777` it (I'm using Docker for Windows, so I found a Windows equivalent `icacls data /grant Everyone:F`),
- `docker-compose up -d`,
- Finally, To add an individual link run

`echo "https://example.com" | docker-compose exec -T archivebox /bin/archive`

I expected the outputted archive data to be stored in my data/ volume but it does not appear to be, and I get the following error `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec format error": unknown`

Comment: `exec format error` sounds like the program can't be executed, such as missing a hashbang (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env python`), or the program in the hashbang is missing. Note that `chmod 777` is not a good idea, anyone can wrote to it! It's better to just use `chmod 755` to make it readable and executable for everyone, but writeable just for the owner.

Answer (score 0):

/bin/archive is a path form the docker container and running docker exec with a pathfile actually search the pathfile on your host, and the error ,means your command line can not find archivebox or /bin/archive and run it