# [How to]: Run docker from shell script running in local and then execute other runs?

Tags: python, docker, shell, containers, ubuntu-18.04

I've to build a shell script which:

1. Runs a docker container,
2. Then runs a python script inside it,
3. Comes out of docker and sleeps for 10 seconds and
4. Then runs a python script in local machine.

I created a sample shell script which is going inside after running the docker and upon manual exiting (exit command) it stops the docker, whereas I want it to run continuously. How to build such a shell script to do the same?

Sample:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
docker run -it -v /home/ubuntu/Downloads/docker_work/test_py_app/app:/workspace/app -p 8881:8888 -p 5002:5002 --gpus all --rm nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:20.08-py3

exit
```

Comment: Have you tried adding it in crontab? Or even if possible, make it as a init service in your Ubuntu.

Comment: Think of `docker run` as something that runs a single command.  Your outer script can't run commands in it; the `docker run` itself should do the thing the container is going to do.  (You'd have very similar trouble if you tried to run a nested `bash` and inside that ran more commands.)

Comment: @Saeed My purpose is not to run when Ubuntu starts. My purpose is a one-click deployment of my solution.

Comment: @DavidMaze what can I do then? My requirement is very simple as stated as steps above.

Answer (score 0):

so you need keep the container running forever, right? Here is the trick

> docker run -d -v /home/ubuntu/Downloads/docker_work/test_py_app/app:/workspace/app -p 8881:8888 -p 5002:5002 --gpus all --name pytorch_container   nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:20.08-py3 tail -f /dev/null

three changes:

- change to run with `-d` as running container in background
- give the container name `--name`, so you can re-use it later
- run `tail -f /dev/null` wthin container to keep the container running.

Now you are fine to run script inside or outside container.

if you need run script inside,

```
docker exec -ti pytorch_container /workspace/test/test.py
```

you are fine to run with other commands outside container.

Comment: This is my code inside the docker: /workspace/test/test.py. When I use this command (in my local machine where the docker is running): "sudo docker exec -ti pytorch_container /workspace/test/test.py", I get this error: "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec format error": unknown", how to solve it? The job runs inside the docker without error, it is tested and a sample log writing is written in it to prove it runs. Please help!

Comment: I updated the command to: "sudo docker exec -ti pytorch_container python /workspace/test/test.py", now it shows no errors, but the log file is not generated, whereas when I run directly in docker, it generates the log file as expected. No error and no log is confusing me.

Comment: for your OCI error, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57223252/498256

Comment: for your py script, generate logs, where are the logs generated? local folder or on console?